# Which method to choose for adding accelerator to JMenuitem?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I searched the web and found two ways to add an accelerator to a JMenuItem. Will the choice which one to use have any possible effect on the program?

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control X"););
```

Or

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('X', KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
```

Comment: Examine the difference [`getKeyStroke(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.String)) and          [`getKeyStroke(Character keyChar,int modifiers)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.Character,int)) .  As for me second is more preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this one:

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyEvent.VK_X, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
```

Because it uses both `KeyEvent` constants and you can rely on Java mapping the appropriate character/key. As a general practice I prefer use constants if available because you can trust on they do what is intended to.